# Oracle responsys - send record to table in warehouse on event

Tags: responsys

I'm trying to figure out how to send Responsys record/s to a table in our data warehouse (MS SQL) in real time, when triggered to do so from an interaction event.

Use case is-
- Mass email is sent
- Customer X interacts with email (e.g. open, click)
- Responsys sends contact along with unique identifier (let's call it 'customer_key') and phone number to the table in the warehouse, within several minutes of customer interaction

Once in the table I can pass to our third party call centre platform.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks
Alex

Answer (score 1):

From what I know of Responsys, the most you can download interaction data is 6 times a day via the Export Event Data Feed.

If you need it more often than that I think you will to set up a filter in Responsys that checks user interactions in the last 15 mins.  And then schedule a daily download per 15 mins interval via connect.

It would have to be 15 mins as you can only schedule a custom download within a 15 min window on responsys.

You'd then need to automate downloading the file, loading and importing.

I highly doubt this is responsive enough for you however!